# Unexpected behavior with RxJava2 PublishSubject

Tags: rx-java2

I have the following code which uses a `PublishSubject`.

```
val subject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

val o1: Observable<String> =
        subject.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).map { i: Int ->
            println("${Thread.currentThread()} | ${Date()} | map => $i")
            i.toString()
        }

o1.subscribe {
    println("${Thread.currentThread()} | ${Date()} | direct subscription (1) => $it")
}

o1.subscribe {
    println("${Thread.currentThread()} | ${Date()} | direct subscription (2) => $it")
}

o1.subscribe {
    println("${Thread.currentThread()} | ${Date()} | direct subscription (3) => $it")
}

println("${Thread.currentThread()} | ${Date()} | submitting 1")

subject.onNext(1)
```

1) I create an `Observable` from it and map it (for the purpose of this example I am just converting to a `String`) => `o1`.

2) I then subscribe to `o1` 3 times.

3) Finally I "publish" an event by calling `subject.onNext(1)`.

To my surprise I am getting the following output:

```
Thread[main,5,main] | Mon Jun 19 09:46:37 PDT 2017 | submitting 1
Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main] | Mon Jun 19 09:46:37 PDT 2017 | map => 1
Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-2,5,main] | Mon Jun 19 09:46:37 PDT 2017 | map => 1
Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-3,5,main] | Mon Jun 19 09:46:37 PDT 2017 | map => 1
Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main] | Mon Jun 19 09:46:37 PDT 2017 | direct subscription (1) => 1
Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-2,5,main] | Mon Jun 19 09:46:37 PDT 2017 | direct subscription (2) => 1
Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-3,5,main] | Mon Jun 19 09:46:37 PDT 2017 | direct subscription (3) => 1
```

`map` ends up being called 3 times and I don't understand why since I am subscribing to `o1` which should happen after `map` has occurred. I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Yan

Comment: You subscribe to `o1` three times, each creating an independent sequence up until the `PublishSubject` that will dispatch the `onNext` to all 3 chains.

Comment: You say "up until the `PublishSubject`": why is it going all the way to the subject? Can you point me to where this would be explained? And if this is normal behavior is there a way to transform the stream after the map so that it doesn't do that?

Comment: Because from the perspective of all 3 subscribers, PublishSubject is a multicasting source that signals events to them through independent chains established by the subscribe() calls.

Comment: Applying operators on a Subject generally don't make the whole chain hot because those operator elements only get attached to the source Subject only when they are subscribed to. Thus, multiple subscriptions will yield multiple channels to the same upstream Subject.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. So how do you avoid this? What if I had `subject.map(...).filter(...).map(...)....` a complex and computation heavy series of transforms. That would be very expensive to have each subscription redo the same computation. How would you go about it?

Comment: Use `publish` (or another `PublishSubject` at the very end) to make the sequence hot from that point on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the comments:*

You subscribe to `o1` three times, each creating an independent sequence up until the `PublishSubject` that will dispatch the `onNext` to all 3 chains.

From the perspective of all 3 subscribers, `PublishSubject` is a multicasting source that signals events to them through independent chains established by the `subscribe()` calls.

Applying operators on a `Subject` generally don't make the whole chain hot because those operator elements only get attached to the source `Subject` only when they are subscribed to. Thus, multiple subscriptions will yield multiple channels to the same upstream `Subject`.

Use `publish` to get a `ConnectableObservable` (or another `PublishSubject` at the very end) to make the sequence hot from that point on.

Comment: I confirm that by adding `.publish.autoConnect()` after `map` it does the right thing. I am not 100% sure what you mean by _or another `PublishSubject`_ but the way I made it work was by adding `.subscribe { otherSubject.onNext(it) }` and have the subscriptions happen on this other subject instead.

Comment: To close the loop, I created a gist to demonstrate the 2 options https://gist.github.com/ypujante/2ab3c3a135272ea4bc4554cbfc287ca7. In the end I chose the option with the 2nd subject as it seems cleaner to me.